# Flutter, using Streambuilder inside endDrawer?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have some challanges getting my data from `Firestore` inside my `endDrawer`.
I am using a `StreamBuilder` to fetch my data, and this is working outside of my `endDrawer`. It returns the text `'No alerts'`, so it returns null.

Here is my code:

```
endDrawer: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: appBarHeight + 1),
          child: Drawer(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: const Text('Alerts',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14),),
                ),
                Divider(),
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: StreamBuilder(
                      stream: _notifications,
                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                          return const Text ('No alerts');
                        }
                        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.waiting) {
                          return const Text('Please wait...');
                        }

                        return ListView.builder(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            DocumentSnapshot documentsnapshot = snapshot.data!
                                .docs[index];

                            var details  = documentsnapshot['Details'];

                            return GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                print(documentsnapshot['Name']);


                              },
                              child: Card(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      if (details == 'Service') Row(

                                        children: [
                                          Text(documentsnapshot['Info'], style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 10,
                                          ),),
                                          Text(' '),
                                          Text(documentsnapshot['Name'], style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 10,
                                          ),),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      if(details == 'Error') Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Text(documentsnapshot['Info'], style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 10,
                                          ),),
                                          Text(' '),
                                          Text(documentsnapshot['Name'], style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 10,
                                          ),),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      if(details == 'Broken') Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Text(documentsnapshot['Name'], style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 10,
                                          ),),
                                          Text(' '),
                                          Text(documentsnapshot['Info'], style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 10,
                                          ),),
                                        ],
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },


                        );
                      }
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

          ),
        ),
```

Here is my stream:

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _notifications = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('notifications').snapshots();
```

Comment: what do you see if you add `print(snapshot);`?

Comment: can you include _notifications? @Alexander

Comment: @pskink , I get this: AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null, null)

Comment: so it means that `stream: _notifications` did not emit any data, what is `_notifications` taken from?

Comment: I think I found the problem, I used the same stream on something else. When I created a new stream _notifications1, it worked.

Comment: Please post the answer so that the community facing the same issues can refer your answer.